# Arabic words in to a one span and English words into a another span element in the given string

Tags: javascript

**Input**

`var str = "الخدمات المصرفية الدولية ومؤسسات التمويلhgf dfsdf123456dfdfdg dfgdfg fg المصرفية الدولية ومؤسسات التمويل"`

**Output**

`<span class="redClr">الخدمات المصرفية الدولية ومؤسسات التمويل</span>hgf dfsdf123456dfdfdg dfgdfg fg <span class="redClr">المصرفية الدولية ومؤسسات التمويل</span>`

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

I'm checking every character to see if it's latin or arabic, and then adding it to a chunk of text. Every time the alphabet changes, I push the chunk to an array of new strings and restart a new current chunk.

It's not an efficient technique, but it gets the job done. I assume it would be better to work only with indices, rather than every single character.

```js
let body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
let string = "الخدمات المصرفية الدولية ومؤسسات التمويلhgf dfsdf123456dfdfdg dfgdfg fg المصرفية الدولية ومؤسسات التمويل";

let arabic = /[\u0600-\u06FF]/;
let newStrings = [];
let currentChunk = '';

for (let i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
    let currentCharacter = string[i];

    let currentCharacterIsArabic = !!currentCharacter.match(arabic);
    let currentChunkIsArabic = !!currentChunk.match(arabic);

    if (currentCharacter === ' ') {
        // Current character is a space
        currentChunk += currentCharacter;
    } else if (currentCharacterIsArabic) {
        // Current character is arabic
        if (currentChunkIsArabic || currentChunk === '') {
            // Current chunk is arabic or empty
            currentChunk += currentCharacter;
        } else {
            // But current chunk is latin
            newStrings.push(currentChunk);
            currentChunk = currentCharacter;
        }
    } else {
        // Current character is latin
        if (!currentChunkIsArabic || currentChunk === '') {
            // Current chunk is latin or empty
            currentChunk += currentCharacter;
        } else {
            // But current chunk is arabic
            newStrings.push(currentChunk);
            currentChunk = currentCharacter;
        }
    }

    let currentCharacterIsTheLastCharacter = i === string.length - 1;

    if (currentCharacterIsTheLastCharacter) {
        newStrings.push(currentChunk);
    }
}

for (let i = 0; i < newStrings.length; i++) {
    let span = document.createElement("span");
    span.innerHTML = newStrings[i];
    body.appendChild(span);
}
```

Comment: Hi, I need to split arabic char  to one span and english characters to one span

Answer (score 0):

```js
var str = "الخدمات المصرفية الدولية ومؤسسات التمويل hgf dfsdf123456dfdfdg dfgdfg fg المصرفية الدولية ومؤسسات التمويل";

var splittedString = str.split(" ");
var arabicPattern = /[\u0600-\u06FF]/;
var arabicKeywords = "";
var englishKeywords = "";

  for(var i=0; i<splittedString.length; i++){
     if(arabicPattern.test(splittedString[i])){
       arabicKeywords = arabicKeywords+ " " +splittedString[i];
      } else {
       englishKeywords = englishKeywords+ " " +splittedString[i];
      }  
    }
    
    document.getElementById("Arabic").innerHTML = arabicKeywords;
    
    document.getElementById("English").innerHTML = englishKeywords;
```

```html
<div>
<span style="background-color:#b3f297" id="Arabic"/>
</div>

<div>
<span style="background-color:#00ffff" id="English"/>
</div>
```

Comment: I have separated the string based on their Unicode characters.

Comment: Ok bro, 
I need a output as below type,

<span class="redClr">الخدمات المصرفية الدولية ومؤسسات التمويل</span>hgf dfsdf123456dfdfdg dfgdfg fg <span class="redClr">المصرفية الدولية ومؤسسات التمويل</span>